# blank window after clicking run module in VIDLE

Tags: python, windows, macos, vpython

I just started learning vPython for my physics project. I was trying out some simple code from the visual library and everything ran great for the first half an our but after I close vPython completely and restarted it my test application doesn't "run" anymore. It shows a blank window and whenever I try to interact with it it shows "not responding". I'm running Windows 10 Pro 64bit with 64-bit Python-2.7.9 and VPython-Win-64-Py2.7-6.11 from vPython.org. I've tried rebooting my computer and reinstalling both Python and vPython but nothing helps. I then transfered my projects to my MacBook Pro and everything runs perfectly. Is there any solution for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unistalling and then re-installing Python? I know it's not the most professional answer, but...

Comment: I'm sorry but i guess i figured it out. I'm supposed to run with VIDLE but when i right click on the file in Windows Explorer it says edit with "IDLE" and that prevents the script to run.